# Wifi not connecting on Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ubuntu

I have tried using the on-board Wi-Fi as well as a USB Wi-Fi adapter on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04. After putting in the Wi-Fi password, I see the Wi-Fi showing up as connected. In about 6 or so seconds, the authentication window pops up and wants me to enter the password again. It keeps on repeating.

I have tried setting up the Wi-Fi manually as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf network { ssid = "mySSID" psk = "my password" }
```

Please suggest a solution if you have solved this problem.

Comment: Your best bet for functioning software is to use what everyone else is using. Try rasbian instead.

Answer (score 4):

For me, worked by restarting the service. Do this: `sudo service NetworkManager restart`

Answer (score 2):

> This Answer is TOTALLY wrong and misleading! NetworkManager does NOT use `/etc/network/interfaces`

I use a similar method as on Raspbian.

I put the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` (I think this is the part you are missing):

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

And then I put the details to the `/ect/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
country=GB

network={
    ssid="MyWifiNetwork"
    psk="myP4ssw0rd"
}
```

It works for me with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

`Ubuntu Mate` uses `NetworkManager` which stores its configuration files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

If you want to use `MATE` set it up in the normal manner via the GUI, rather than trying to fiddle with the rather complex `NetworkManager` files.

Answer (score 0):

> Create a new network and setup a Static IP manually ; Establish
> automatic connection.

In raspberry pi terminal,

$ `nmcli dev wifi`

```
*  SSID                MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY    
*  myconnection        Infra  6     54 Mbit/s  91      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
```

$ `sudo nmcli dev wifi con "myconnection" password "mypassword" name "myconnection"`

$ `sudo nmcli con edit "myconnection"`

```
   ===| nmcli interactive connection editor |===
    ...
    nmcli> set ipv4.method manual
    nmcli> set ipv4.addr 192.168.43.5/24,192.168.43.7/24,192.168.43.55/24
    nmcli> set ipv4.gateway 192.168.43.1
    nmcli> set ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
    nmcli> set connection.autoconnect yes
    nmcli> save persistent
    nmcli> quit
```

$  `sudo service network-manager restart`

$  `ifconfig`

**for more information** : [how to configure your raspberry pi wifi](https://gist.github.com/vfdev-5/10b9801db56e71ba17988683f863e84e)

Comment: The question is about Ubuntu 16.04!