# Wifi not connecting on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 19.10

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, pi-4

I installed Ubuntu Server 19.10 on a Raspberry Pi 4 with no ethernet connection available, and I was initially able to get it to connect to wifi with `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient`. That allowed me to download and install lubuntu-desktop. Having started the desktop environment, though, it will no longer connect to wifi. If I try to connect through the GUI, it just keeps disconnecting and asking me for the password over and over again. Meanwhile, if I open a terminal and try to connect "manually" as I did the first time, I get the following output from `wpa_suplicant`:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWPMSKA]: Connection timed out
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWPMSKA]: Connection timed out
```

and `sudo dhclient wlan0` just hangs indefinitely.

I have tried restarting the NetworkManager service, restarting the whole computer, and manually editing `/etc/network/interfaces` as suggested [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67997/112519).

EDIT: I tried re-imaging my SD card, and verified that I could connect to WIFI on the terminal again. I then installed Ubuntu MATE instead of lubuntu, and now whenever I try to connect it just sits for a while and the gives me a notification saying "You have been disconnected". I *can* still connect via command line with `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient` now, and Firefox works, but the system GUI remains unaware that it is in fact connected to WIFI.

Comment: NetworkManager does NOT use interfaces! You picked the one TOTALLY wrong Answer. It is possible to configure manually, but far from straightforward

Comment: PS AFAIK Ubuntu Server 19.10 doesn't use either NetworkManager or /etc/network/interfaces, but `systemd-networkd`

Comment: @Logan R. Kearsley. Wait for wi-fi to scan at least 5 minutes or more. then you see list of wi-fi users.